# Does `return` in a .then() callback return from inner or outer scope?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, return

Does line 17 `return` return from the blue or red scope?

[image]

Comment: `isAuthenticated()` is an asynch call, when it executes it will return `true` which will then get returned from the function.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with promises. A `return` statement always returns from the innermost function that it is located in.

However, the [magic of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) is that the return value of the `then` callback becomes the resolution value of the outer promise, which is the one you are returning from the outer function.

Comment: let me get this straight, `.then()`'s callback is fired after `isAuthenticated()` resolves the promise's value (which gets passed to `authenticated` argument).

So if i didn't call `.then()` and return `true`, my promise still wouldn't contain the value I `resolve()`'d in the callback fired when creating the promise initially?

Comment: -- Also, do we return a promise with an undefined value before `.then()` is asynchronously called?

If I wanted to use this promise in the function that called `canActivate()`, would i need to perform some null check to ensure `.then()` has completed?

Is `.then()` even called asynchronously?

Comment: I promise to pay you one million US dollars. How much money (of mine) do you have right now? None, because the promise has not been fulfilled (and never will be, trust me :)). You can attach a `then` to that promise (then, you'll buy a Ferrari), but you can't actually do that until you get that million dollars (well, I don't know your credit rating, but let's not digress). "Promise" was one of the great names made in software, in my opinion, because it captures what is happening. @TheThing

Comment: @TheThing "*then()'s callback is fired after isAuthenticated() resolves the promise*" - yes. "*Do we return a promise with an undefined value before .then() is asynchronously called?*" - no, we return an *unresolved* promise that will later be fulfilled or rejected. And `.then()` itself is called synchronously, to create that promise, it is the callback that you are passing that is always called asynchronously.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks.

My confusion is whether we can/should handle the promise outside of the `.then()` block, since we technically could be returning it to a calling function. 

Mostly use-case oriented

Comment: @TheThing Yes, you should in general always return the promise to your caller (so that they at least can wait until you're done, or even better use your result value), and yes, the caller should then handle that promise by chaining more `.then(…)` calls to it.

Comment: @Bergi thanks. Is it accepted to actually access/use the promise outside the function passed to `then()` (EX: in the function calling `canActivate()` which receives an unfulfilled promise), and if so, how do we usually check that the promise has been resolved since the `.then(expr)` `expr` function runs asynchronously and the promise may not have been fulfilled yet?

Comment: @Bergi, oh right, you would just chain another `.then()` call in a different scope. Makes a lot of sense.

Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @Bergi final question, if the `.then()` callback is fired asynchronously, would the surrounding scope not get destroyed when returning the unresolved promise? Does the unexecuted callback within `.then()` prevent that from happening to prevent errors?

Does it run with no issue despite the scope being destroyed since the only member variable we reference is a reference to a global injection (`this.router`).

This is in angular by the way, let me know if there's angular stuff going on you aren't familiar with here.

Comment: @TheThing That's what [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) are for

Answer (score 0):

First: please, don't post code as embedded images, it makes answering so much harder.

Second: you can just as well introduce an intermediate variable, and write your function this way:

```
canActivate() {
    const returnedPromise = this.authService.isAuthenticated()
        .then(this.processAuthenticationValue);

    return returnedPromise;
}


private processAuthenticationValue = (authenticated: boolean) => {
    if (authenticated) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

So, here's what happens: `isAuthenticated()` is called and returns some promise. A `then` is attached at the end of its promise chain (that `then` is defined in the `processAuthenticationValue` method). What is returned from `canActivate` is the entire chain.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I don't think this will work. What if the `.then` fires after `return`?

Comment: @Siddharth that's not a problem. First, that's not the case of "if", the execution _will_ reach the `return` statement before what's under `then` is executed. Second, promises exist solely for the purpose of handling this.